# calling an activity from a non-activity(simple layout) through separate class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to call an activity from a non-activity class (simple class).

I created a tabbed activity. then I created a layout for fragments. and created a separate class in which I am doing some validation and calling an activity. but I am unable to start the activity from that non-activity class.

this is the function in which i am having problem

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guarding_services_layout, container, false);

    p_guard_srvc = p_guard_srvc.findViewById(R.id.guard_booknow_btn);

    p_guard_srvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //this line, i am unable to write the correct method
            Intent i = new Intent( GuardingScreen.this , HomeScreen.class);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: instead of `GuardingScreen.this` use `getActivity()`

Comment: It's because of context. Just pass a context to your class constructor and call activity via that context.

Comment: you need to call start activity "startActivity(your intent)" to start that activity

Comment: if your are  inside a fragement you can get the hosting activity by using `getActivity()` or `getContext()` to get context view current running activity

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guarding_services_layout, container, false);

    p_guard_srvc = p_guard_srvc.findViewById(R.id.guard_booknow_btn);
    p_guard_srvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent i = new Intent( getActivity() , HomeScreen.class);
             getActivity().startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Read the question carefully. OP wants to call activity from _non-activity_ class

Answer (score 0):

You should pass activity context to your non-activity class, and start your activity using context. for example: you can pass activity context in Non-Activity class's constructor or you can make a setter method for context.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,YourClassName.class));
```

Comment: i am unable to get the context. i had it going on in my mind! but still, i am unable to resolve it. i have tried various methods. `getApplicationContext()`, `getActivitiy()`, have also tried making an object of the class of which i want. also tried getting the view of the layout. but still i'm unable to get the context.

Comment: Add Context in your Non-Activity class's constructor from your activityLike this `new YourClass(context);`

Comment: as from your above code this code is of Fragment class and you can have context in fragment also. so tell mne what is your non-activity class?

Comment: well it seems that i am calling my FREGMENT class (which is `GuardingScreen` a non-activity class) cuz i created it and then extend it with FRAGMENT....!! and i am trying to call the activity class from this FREGMENT extended class....!!

Comment: You should replace your fragment instead of calling it as Activity, Fragment is not an activity perhaps it's a sub-activity, which work in an activity context.